# how to use django mailer without PINAX

Tags: django, django-mailer

I want to use django-mailer without PINAX. When I run `./manager.py send_mail`
it prints:

```
Unknown command: 'send_mail'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

How do I fix this?

```
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Sep 22 2007, 01:43:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (SUSE Linux)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> 'mailer' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS
True
>>> 

$./manage.py send_mail
Unknown command: 'send_mail'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

and I used easy_install django-mailer to install the mailer, and the django version
is

```
    VERSION = (1, 1, 1, 'final', 0)
```

and mailer version is 0.1.0

Comment: Have you installed it and added it to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: now i know why:

use git clone and python ./setup.py install to re-install the mailer, and it worked!  

Maybe the easy_install won't work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things to double check:

1. Did you install django-mailer?
2. Is mailer in your PYTHONPATH?  When you import mailer, are you getting the expected module (version and expected path)?
3. Is mailer listed in your INSTALLED_APPS?

> ```
> $ ./manage.py shell
> >>> import mailer
> >>> mailer.get_version()
> '0.1.0'
> >>> mailer.__file__
> /PATH/TO/YOUR/PYTHON/LIBS/mailer/__init__.py
> >>> # did it import?  did you get the expected version?  expected path?  
> >>> # good, django-mailer is in your PYTHONPATH.  now verify project settings.
> >>> from django.conf import settings
> >>> 'mailer' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS
> True
> ```

At this point you should see send_mail in the list of available manage.py subcommands.

> $ ./manage.py --help
>      Usage: manage.py subcommand [options] [args]
>      [...]
>      runserver
>      send_mail
>      shell
>      [...]
>      $

After than you will also want to make sure that you are running `./manage.py send_mail` via a cron job.

```
* * * * * (cd $YOUR_PROJECT; /usr/bin/python manage.py send_mail >> cron_mail.log 2>&1)  
0,20,40 * * * * (cd $YOUR_PROJECT; /usr/bin/python manage.py retry_deferred >> cron_mail_deferred.log 2>&1)
```

There is no need to actually set these two cronjobs up during development, just look for your messages via the admin.

The django-mailer module has usage instructions but this should get you up and running.

Comment: Added a check to make sure the project can import mailer.  The question was updated to confirm that django-mailer was installed via easy_install but the "Unknown command" error suggests that mailer might not be available via the current PYTHONPATH environment setting.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just download it from [django-mailer](http://github.com/jtauber/django-mailer) and install it separately?